# Why does the batch file not copy files when invoked from Windows Forms app but it works from Console app?

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

I have a Console app and a Winforms app that do the same. The common functionality is in a class being reused by both.

The CopyRequiredFile, starts a windows batch file which uses **xcopy to copy  files from a network folder to a local drive**. But, **when called from the Windows Forms app it doesn't copy the files**.

I am a novice developer trying to develop framework and some internal tools for UI automation.

Why does it work to copy the files when I invoke the functionality from the Console application, but not from the Windows Forms Application?

**My Console App:**

```
public class Program
    {
        private static readonly Action<string> OutputAction = s => Console.WriteLine(s);
        private static readonly IProgress<string> Progress = new Progress<string>(OutputAction);

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HelpersCopy.CreateRequiredDirectories(Progress);
            HelpersCopy.CopyRequiredFiles(Progress, true);
            HelpersCopy.StartHub(Progress);
            HelpersCopy.StartNode(Progress);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

**My Windows Forms app:** Only code that is relevant to this question.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Action<string> outputAction = s => txtOutput.InvokeEx(t => t.Text += s + Environment.NewLine);
            IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(outputAction);

            txtOutput.Clear();
            HelpersCopy.CreateRequiredDirectories(progress);
            HelpersCopy.CopyRequiredFiles(progress, true);
            HelpersCopy.StartHub(progress);
            HelpersCopy.StartNode(progress);
        }
```

*InvokeEx is an extension method to invoke the action if required. Help from stackoverflow!*

Unfortunately, I cannot post images because I don't have the required points. So, please see the output images here: https://www.flickr.com/photos/61600076@N05/sets/72157649781440604/

**Helpers Class Code** *Please let me know if this code is not required in the question.*

```
public class HelpersCopy
    {
        public static void CopyRequiredFiles(IProgress<string> progress, bool hideWindow = false)
        {
            progress.Report(string.Format("Copying latest version of executables...{0}", Environment.NewLine));
            var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            ExecuteCommand(String.Format(@"{0}\Copy latest Selenium files.bat", currentDirectory), progress, hideWindow: hideWindow);
            progress.Report(string.Format("\r\nLatest version of executables copied successfully{0}", Environment.NewLine));
        }

        private static void ExecuteCommand(string fileName, IProgress<string> progress, string command = null, bool hideWindow = true)
        {
            if (hideWindow)
            {
                var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName, command)
                {

                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    // *** Redirect the output ***
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true
                };

                var process = new Process { StartInfo = processInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true };
                process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => progress.Report(args.Data);
                process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => progress.Report(args.Data);
                var started = process.Start();
                progress.Report(string.Format("process started: {0}", started));
                progress.Report(string.Format("process id: {0}", process.Id));
                progress.Report(string.Format("process start info: {0} {1}", process.StartInfo.FileName, process.StartInfo.UserName));
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.WaitForExit();

                int ExitCode = process.ExitCode;

                progress.Report(string.Format("ExitCode: {0}{1}", ExitCode, Environment.NewLine));
                process.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                var process = Process.Start(fileName, command);
                if (process.HasExited)
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Process exited. Exit code: {0}", process.ExitCode));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**My batch file**

```
@echo off

echo Deleting existing mappings...

net use z: /delete /yes

echo Mapping network drives...

net use z: \\company-filestore\Selenium /user:company-filestore\Automation Selen1um

z:
cd "Hub and Node Executables"

echo Copying latest Selenium jars...
xcopy "z:\Hub and Node Executables" "C:\Selenium\" /R /Y /S /Z
echo Finished copying latest Selenium jars...

echo All done
```

Comment: can you please condense this question a bit to emphasize the important parts? there's a lot of noise

Comment: Sure @DLeh. I will try and remove unnecessary bits of code and state the desired behaviour properly.

Comment: I tried rewriting the statement of your question so it is more clear, hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Dzyann. Much more precise and to the point. Appreciate everybody's help here.

Comment: I would also advise to remove the code of your helper class that is not relevant for this post and to add at least one part of the code that you use for copying the files.

Comment: Is the winforms app running with the same permissions as the console?

Comment: @Aidanapword yes, I made sure that both apps are running with exactly same permissions (Run as Administrator), but the issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in winforms app (although, there was never any issue in console app using the same code) was being caused by a bug in xcopy in that when you redirect its output you need to redirect its input as well. So, adding this line to the ProcessInfo object in my code, fixed the issue.

```
RedirectStandardInput = true
```

**More information on the issue is here:** https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ab3c0cc7-83c2-4a86-9188-40588b7d1a52/processstart-of-xcopy-only-works-under-the-debugger?forum=netfxbcl

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested placing the batch file in the same folder where the Windows Forms exe is available?
Have you tried running the windows forms app with Admin rights?
Just to knockout the possibility of insufficient permissions.

have you also verified the user context with which the code is executed and if the folder has permissions for the user context?

Comment: Tried running the winforms app with "Run as Administrator" option, but issue still exists. Both apps have exactly same permissions, i.e., I tried running console app normally and with admin rights and it works as expected, whereas, the winforms app whether run normally or with admin rights fails to copy the required files. The batch file, console exe and winforms exe are all in the same folder.

Comment: Hi, wellcome to stackoverflow, this would be a Comment and not an answer.